# Storing and retrieving state from store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I am trying to save a `userToken` inside a Redux store and retrieve it. In my `index.js` I wrap my `App` with `Provider`, which takes `store` as prop:

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import rootReducer from "./reducers/rootReducer";

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

My `rootReducer` looks like this:

```
//Helper functions
import { validateLoginAttempt } from "../helpers/validateLoginAttempt";

const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "login":
      const isLoggedIn = validateLoginAttempt(action.payload);
    default:
      console.log("default");
      break;
  }
};

export default rootReducer;
```

I have defined a helper function `validateLoginAttempt`:

```
export const validateLoginAttempt = payload => {
  if (typeof payload.data.token !== "undefined") {
    //Saves in localstorage correctly.
    localStorage.setItem("userToken", payload.data.token);

    return true;
  }

  return false;
};
```

In one of my functional components, I have a `fetch()` procedure, which by the end of request to an API, `dispatch()`'es action I defined in my `rootReducer`:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
<...>
.then(data => {
  dispatch({ type: "login", payload: { data } });
  history.push("/");
})
```

Flow of this `useCase` works as intended, at least from what I understand, the value gets stored in `localStorage` (which I assume is not a Redux `store`?). In another of my components I am trying to retrieve `userToken` like this:

```
const userToken = useSelector(state => state.userToken);
```

This gives me an `error`:

```
Error: An error occured while selecting the store state: Cannot read property 'userToken' of undefined.
```

If I try to `getStore` as follows in my `App` component, I get `store undefined`:

```
const store = useStore();
console.log("store", store.getState());
```

Could someone put me on a right track, cannot figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems, but the biggest one is related to the [basics of reducers](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers):

> The reducer is a pure function that takes the previous state and an action, and **returns the next state**.

You don't return anything from the reducer (implicitly `return undefined`), thus causing the TypeError `Cannot read property 'userToken' of undefined.`:

```
const initialState = {};
const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "login": {
      return {...state, userToken: action.payload.data.token};
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

And "a pure function" means no side effects, so the `localStorage.setItem` inside `validateLoginAttempt` has no place in a reducer and should be placed inside the action creator:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
...
.then(data => {
  const isLoggedIn = validateLoginAttempt(data);
  if (isLoggedIn) {
    dispatch({ type: "login", payload: { data } });
    history.push("/");
  } else {
    console.error("not logged in")
  }
})
```

Comment: thank you. In addition to `return {...state, userToken: action.payload.data.token};` . What would be a correct way to remove the same `userToken` from store?

Comment: something like `case 'logout': return {...state, userToken: null}`